# How to execute a procedure inside a package in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, package

**I have seen some answers related to this question. But, my issue is not yet resolved.**

I have 3 stored procs in my oracle package.

*I am trying to execute a single porcedure, but i guess entire package is getting executed.*

**The syntax i am using :**

**Stored Proc with no input or output params**

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
PackageName.Sp1;
END;
```

Some one , please help me where i am going wrong ?

Comment: If you're getting errors during recompilaton/revalidation of the package, your call is now working (with Rahul's original answer), but your package is just broken. After creating the package do `show errors`, or query the `user_errors` view, to see what is actually wrong. If you can't fix it then ask a new question about that as it is not related to how you're calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute it like below. Take out the `DECLARE` part since there is no parameter needs to be declared.

```
BEGIN
PackageName.Sp1;
END;
```

Comment: i am getting many errors like : errors during recompilaton/revalidation of package

Comment: @SaiAvinash, not that sure but see my edited answer. Try now.

Comment: You do need the `begin`/`end` around a procedure call, You don't need the `declare` in this example, so your first version was right. @SaiAvinash - errors during recompilation are not because of how you're calling it, your package has a problem.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Thanks for pointing that. since it's a single statement I though `begin .. end` construct is not needed. still not sure, why it's needed though?

Comment: You can only ever call a procedure in a PL/SQL context; you can call a function in a PL/SQL context or (usually) from a `select`. SQL*Plus does have the `execute PackageName.Sp1` shorthand but that just generates the anonymous block for you.

Comment: @AlexPoole..You are spot on..There are errors in the others procedures of the package which is causing the entire package compilation to fail.Now, i corrected those errors and was able to compile and execute them.Thanks for your time..

Comment: @Rahul..Yes when we have either IN or OUT Parameters, we need DECLARE. Thanks for your thoughts